# Twitter bot incorrectly tweets answers that aren't "great"

Tags: discussion

The [StackScifi Twitter account](http://twitter.com/StackSciFi) incorrectly detects great answers.

For [example](http://twitter.com/#!/StackSciFi/status/102445197442547712):

> Great answer: Which Game of Thrones books have been televised as of September 2011? http://t.co/kkllt7g #asongoficeandfire

A great answer requires a score > 100, and we [don't have any yet](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/badges/40/great-answer) (we do have [many good answers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/badges/39/good-answer)).

If this is the Twitter account having a different definition of "great" than badges do, then IMO that's confusing, and it would be better to use the same names in both places (the above answer only has 5 votes, so it's not even a "good" answer).

Comment: BTW, the recent addition of "can you answer" and featuring answers (when they do actually have a lot of votes) are great.

Comment: (The t.co link going to a bit.ly link going to SE isn't so great...)

Comment: yeah, we'll definitely fix the double-shortening.. since we started, I think Twitter introduced their own native URL shortener.

Answer (score 2):

This does not *literally* mean "Great Answer" as in the badge.

In the context of Twitter, it means an answer with score +3 or better. [Another example](http://twitter.com/#!/StackGardening/status/102358797540012034). (at +4 now because I upvoted it, but at the time...)

As for the complete 'spec' of what gets tweeted, we do a few new things now:

[Would allowing moderators to update their Stack Exchange sites' Twitter accounts improve visibility and offer more value?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92235/would-allowing-moderators-to-update-their-stack-exchange-sites-twitter-accounts/101340#101340)

Comment: Was there a reason for choosing a score of 3?  That seems extremely low.  Seeing interesting answers pop up is great (and I'm more likely to miss those than questions), but nearly any answer can get a score of 3, even on our little site.  (Unless "interesting" is a significant factor, but it doesn't seem a great algorithm so far, for the accounts that I'm following).